# vue axios.get to fetch images from imgur

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, imgur

While trying to fetch all images from the Galleries template I am receiving the following error/warn notification: "**Property "token" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance**". instead of displaying the images I receive the following: `<img src="function link() { [native code] }">` What am I missing?

## Galleries.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <img v-for="image in allImages" :src="image.link" :key="image.id" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "Galleries",
  computed: mapGetters(["allImages"]),
  methods: mapActions(["fetchImages"]),
  created() {
    this.fetchImages();
  }
};
</script>
```

## imgur.js

```js
import qs from 'qs';
import axios from 'axios';

const CLIENT_ID = 'e28971925a8d43c';
const ROOT_URL = 'https://api.imgur.com';

export default {
    login() {
        const querystring = {
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            response_type: 'token',
        };
        window.location = `${ROOT_URL}/oauth2/authorize?${qs.stringify(querystring)}`
    },
    fetchImages(token) {
        return axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/3/account/me/image/`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        });
    },
    uploadImages(images, token) {
        const promises = Array.from(images).map(image => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('image', image);
            return axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/3/image`, formData, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            });
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }
};
```

## images.js

```js
import api from '../../api/imgur';
import { router } from '../../main';

const state = {
    images: []
};

const getters = {
    allImages: state => state.images

};

const mutations = {
    setImages: (state, images) => {
        state.images = images;
    }
};

const actions = {
    async fetchImages({ rootState, commit }) {
        const { token } = rootState.auth;
        const response = await api.fetchImages(token);
        commit('setImages', response.data.data);
    },
    async uploadImages({ rootState }, images) {
        // Get the access token
        const { token } = rootState.auth;
        // Call our API module to do the upload
        await api.uploadImages(images, token);

        // Redirect use to the gallery page
        router.push('/galleries');


    }
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions
}
```

## auth.js

```js
import api from '../../api/imgur';
import qs from 'qs';
import { router } from '../../main';


const state = {
    token: window.localStorage.getItem('imgur_token')
};

const getters = {
    isLoggedIn: state => !!state.token // turn a value into boolean
};

const actions = {
    login: () => {
        api.login();
    },
    finalizeLogin({ commit }, hash) {
        const query = qs.parse(hash.replace('#', ''));
        commit('setToken', query.access_token);
        window.localStorage.setItem('imgur_token', query.access_token);
        router.push('/');
    },
    logout: ({ commit }) => {
        commit('setToken', null);
        window.localStorage.removeItem('imgur_token');
        router.push('/');
    }
};

const mutations = {
    setToken: (state, token) => {
        state.token = token;
    }
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Galaries.vue
// You didn't pass token when calling function `fetchImages`.
created() {
    this.fetchImages(); // missing token here
  }
```

I recommend use token as environment variable for security reason. Never public your token. Should NOT pass it as an argument of a function. Store your token in a `.env` file. You can rewrite your fetchImages as below.

```js
    fetchImages(token) {
        return axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/3/account/me/image/`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.TOKEN}`
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: Thank you. Now the token error is resolved yet I am still getting '<img src="function link() { [native code] }">' I see in the console in the data 'data: {error: "An image ID is required for a GET request to /image", request: "/3/account/me/image/",…}'

Comment: Take a look at your api doc again. Your request was missing image ID. The error message showed clearly.

Comment: That's right yet i do not have a clue from the api doc where should the id be placed. If you look at the Galleries.vue file i am passing (v-bind) the ID as a key.

Comment: Anh :-) do i need to pass the id in the computed function first beside adding it to the img tag? I am a newbie please bare with me :-)